# Dataset.from_generator cannot replicate functionality of numpy arrays as input to 1D Convnet

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am feeding many time series of length 100 and 3 features into a 1D Convnet. I have too many of these to use numpy arrays, therefore I need to use Dataset.from_generator().

The problem is that when I train the model on the dataset, it gives the error:

```
expected conv1d_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 3)
```

The code below demonstrates the problem. The generator produces each element as an expected (100,3) array. Why does the model not recognise the generator output as valid?

Many thanks for any help. Julian

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
def create_timeseries_element():
    # returns a random time series of 100 intervals, each with 3 features,
    # and a random one-hot array of 5 entries
    data = np.random.rand(100,3)
    label = np.eye(5, dtype='int')[np.random.choice(5)]
    return data, label

def data_generator():
    d, l = create_timeseries_element()
    yield (d, l)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 9, activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 9, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256, 5, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256, 5, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

x_train = []
y_train = []
for _ in range(1000):
    d, l = create_timeseries_element()
    x_train.append(d)
    y_train.append(l)
x_train = np.array(x_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)

# train model with numpy arrays - this works
model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32),
                                      output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([100, 3]), tf.TensorShape([5])))
# train model with dataset - this fails
model.fit(ds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model expects a batch/list of samples. You can do that by simply setting batch property while creating your dataset as follows:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32),
                                      output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([100, 3]), tf.TensorShape([5])))
ds = ds.batch(16)
```

You can also do that another way when you prepare sample. In this way, You need to expand the sample dimension so that a sample acts as a batch (you can pass a list of samples too) and you have to do the following modifications in your `output_shapes` of dataset and `create_timeseries_element` function

```
def create_timeseries_element():
    # returns a random time series of 100 intervals, each with 3 features,
    # and a random one-hot array of 5 entries
    # Expand dimensions to create a batch of single sample
    data = np.expand_dims(np.random.rand(100, 3), axis=0)
    label = np.expand_dims(np.eye(5, dtype='int')[np.random.choice(5)], axis=0)
    return data, label

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32), output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None, 100, 3]), tf.TensorShape([None, 5])))
```

The above changes will supply only a single batch (sample for first solution) for each epochs of your dataset. You can generate as much batches (samples for first solution) you want (e.g. 25) by passing a parameter to `data_generator` function while you define your dataset like follows:

```
def data_generator(count=1):
    for _ in range(count):
        d, l = create_timeseries_element()
        yield (d, l)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(data_generator, args=[25], output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32), output_shapes=(tf.TensorShape([None, 100, 3]), tf.TensorShape([None, 5])))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works now. I can see that my mistake was in thinking the generator, in yielding (100,3) arrays, was providing what the model expects. However, the model expects an array of (100,3) arrays (i.e. a batch). I have since discovered that my original code works if ds.batch(32) is used as input to model.fit(). Using batch(32) in that way means the generator code can stay as it was. Huge thanks @bit01

Comment: I suppose, you could see in ValueError, that your model in reality is asking for input (**None**, 100, 3) & you ommited the first axis in generator's output, but it appears when you're batching your samples -- exactly as model demands... or yes - you will have to give it in generator as reply suggests